# How to center a button at the bottom of a FrameLayout in a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nero"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp" />

         ....

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/imprint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="230dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to place the FrameLayout at the bottom of the LinearLayout and all elements in the FrameLayout should be centered. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

In **Frame Layout** Use Layout_Gravity will work

```
 android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
```

Also Use Bottom margin to make it in perfect location from bottom.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

To center the button inside the `FrameLayout` you should add:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

inside the `Button` or:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

inside the `FrameLayout`. And btw, if a `Button` is the only child why are you using a `FrameLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if that would solve the issue, but you can use "wrap_content" as your layout_width in your FrameLayout at the bottom. That would center the FrameLayout, so the views which are in the layout would get centered.